# Is it possible to convert an image to image TensorFlow model to CoreML?

Tags: python, swift, tensorflow, coreml, coremltools

The objective is to convert a TensorFlow model to CoreML using both input and output of type image.

I'm using `Python 3.8` and `TensorFlow 2.4.1`
The model have input and output shape `(1, 128, 128, 3)`
Pixels are floats between -1 and 1.

I'm using this to create the CoreML module:

```py
import coremltools as ct
from coremltools.proto import FeatureTypes_pb2 as ft

input_name = generator.inputs[0].name.split(':')[0]
image_input = ct.ImageType(name=input_name, shape=(1, 128, 128, 3), scale=2 / 255.0, bias=[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0])
mlModel = ct.convert(generator, inputs=[image_input], source="tensorflow")

# Set Output as Image
spec = mlModel.get_spec()
output = spec.description.output[0]
output.type.imageType.colorSpace = ft.ImageFeatureType.ColorSpace.Value('RGB')
output.type.imageType.width = 128
output.type.imageType.height = 128

# Save
new_model = ct.models.MLModel(spec)
new_model.author = '...'
new_model.license = '...'
new_model.short_description = '...'
new_model.input_description[input_name] = 'Input Image'
new_model.output_description[output.name] = 'Predicted Image'
new_model.save("model.mlmodel")

print("Input name: ", input_name)  # -> input_1
print("Output name: ", output.name)  # -> Identity
```

I can test predictions like this (the result is correct):

```py
# image shape=(1, 128, 128, 3), dtype=float32)
prediction = generator(image, training=True)
plt.imshow(prediction[0] * 0.5 + 0.5)
plt.show()
```

The generated model looks like this on Xcode:
[image to image model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzaYb.png)

This is what I'm using on IOS:

```swift
func generateImage(inputImage: UIImage, completion: @escaping (UIImage?)->()) {
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Model(configuration: .init()).model) else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    guard let cgImage = inputImage.cgImage else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    let coreMLRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNPixelBufferObservation] else {
            print("Can't get results: \(request.results) Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        guard let topResult = results.first else {
            print("Can't get top result")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let newImage = UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: topResult.pixelBuffer))
        completion(newImage)
        return
    }
    do {
        try VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:]).perform([coreMLRequest])
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform request. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

This fails with the error: `The VNCoreMLTransform request failed`.
And trying the preview option directly form Xcode also fails.

So I believe the input or the output is not properly setup during conversion.
Is it possible to convert from `(1, 128, 128, 3) float32` to whatever CoreML expects?